# Moving a class derived from istream

Tags: c++, c++11, move, istream

I'm creating a C++ `istream` with a custom `streambuf`. Trying to move this fails because the istream move constructor is protected. To get round this I derived a class from `istream`:

```
struct VectorCharBuf : public streambuf {
    VectorCharBuf(vector<char>& v) {
        setg(v.data(), v.data(), v.data() + v.size());
    }
};

struct IVectorCharStream : public istream {
    IVectorCharStream(VectorCharBuf* contents_buf) : istream(contents_buf) {}
};
```

The default move constructor for this class is not generated because it involves the

> use of deleted function 'std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]'

Further, if I try to declare a move constructor explicitly, as in

```
struct MyIStream : public istream {
    MyIStream(MyIStream&& str) : istream(move(str)) {}
};
```

I get an error "invalid use of void expression". (I'm probably doing something silly in this last case, but I just can't spot it... .)

How can I create a movable `istream`?

Comment: Why do you try to move an actual `std::istream` in the first place? That hardly sounds useful.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, so you can initialize it using `auto variable = MyIstream{};`?

Comment: Then what are you going to do with `variable`? `std::istream` is just a generic base, it does not actually do anything useful by itself.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: the `std::istream` is useful if you supply a custom streambuf.  I'd be quite happy to be able to move a stream derived from `istream`, though.

Comment: Ah I get it. Carry on then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct MyIStream : public istream {
    MyIStream(MyIStream&& str) : istream(move(str)) {}
};
```

> I get an error "invalid use of void expression".

This doesn't work because `basic_ios`, a base class of `istream` contains a member function `void move(basic_ios& _Other)` (for moving the base class).

If you use `std::move(str)` in the constructor, it compiles!

Comment: According to the standard, the `std::istream` move constructor does not move the streambuf (which is why it's protected in the first place), so wouldn't this example wipe the streambuf on move? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create a movable istream?

You can implement your class in terms of your base class' default constructor, instead of the move constructor of the base:

```
struct MyIStream : public istream {
    MyIStream(MyIStream&& str)
   : istream()
   {
       // todo: implement move functionality from str
   }
};
```